# segmasker doubles found intervals

Tags: phylogenetics, segmasker, bugs

During [NCBI BLAST+ segmasker](https://toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/repository/display_tool?repository_id=1d92ebdf7e8d466c&tool_config=%2Fsrv%2Ftoolshed-repos%2Fmain%2F000%2Frepo_241%2Ftools%2Fncbi_blast_plus%2Fncbi_segmasker_wrapper.xml&changeset_revision=5edc472ec434) output exploration, I found out that for some sequences, the program returns the same interval twice:

```
>tr|A0A0D2B4V6|A0A0D2B4V6_9EURO Uncharacterized protein OS=Cladophialophora immunda OX=569365 GN=PV07_04097 PE=3 SV=1
131 - 139
131 - 139
```

This seems not to be a planned behaviour, but maybe someone has an explanation.

The command I ran was:

```
segmasker -in <input_file> -out <output_file> -locut 1.5 -hicut 1.8 -window 15
```

---

Exemplary sequences triggering such an event:

```
>sequence1
MDSHNSSTLIILSLPPKTFVGLDLVSFDSSPNFQGIAKIPVGIHFLYTGTDASLSIRHGRWLNLTSTHPIQVLRWNSDGETLQPVDQNDQTARNAIAAISNGRGLVDYGALQSATSELSTRESQSHDASSLAAAAAAAAADEDRAESTDWPALTAHISSPLLTRILSPDWIVSSISSAPTDTETIPGLSHLEASNALHQLPLDLLPVNLKQTWAGGDIGRARTERARDRSWYLGQLIEQAARPQGGDKTAGAREVLGELQFCFLMVLTLANYSCLEQWKRLLSVFFTCRTALDEVEGYFVQVIRVLRLQIKHVDDVEGGLFELRDESGSAWLRTLWARFRSVVDDADKGERVSLKKEVDALEKLFEGKYGWQSERDILRRGMLELEDGERVEVTMHGVDEDEETGEYAPVIVET
>sequence2
VDKLFKKNAMGNNIFHEIAIQGSLMLLQTIRDNVDGQMDTYLSEINDQNESCITIVADRHRGLLAKDLIEIFVDLGADINETDNWGNTALHYSVFHRDHVLAEWLCQQPGINLNAINNDEHTPLGLAILWNIQSIKTLLESKGARFNNIEFSDSETSDDDDDDDDDGHDENDE
```

Comment: What command are you running? What options?

Comment: Right, I should have include it. `segmasker -in <input_file> -out <output_file> -locut 1.5 -hicut 1.8 -window 15`.

Comment: Could there be something silly like having duplicate sequences in your input? Which are then combined in the output?

Comment: Nah, I've just run *segmasker* on the given example and [got](https://pastebin.pl/view/675aabe7).

Comment: I'm using *segmasker* locally. Installed last week.